# Pull To Refresh Script

Tags: javascript

I've just downloaded `jquery.mobile.pulltorefresh` from [here](https://github.com/funayoi/jquery.mobile.pulltorefresh)

I've uploaded it to my server to test and see if its the right one I want to use... However when you go to it:

[quotesin.com](http://m.quotesin.com/pull/demo.html)

It doesn't work at all. Think I'm having a blonde day, if this is no good does anyone know of any lightweight versions I could use? Rather than Cubiq one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your error is that you mention 3 files that there are not found or can't access

the files are:

```
1. jquery.mobile-1.0.js
2. jquery-1.6.4.min.js
3. jquery.mobile-1.0.css
```

you can test this by open your link on google chrome them right click on the page then click inspect element

after that choose resources tab, then expand the script link in the side tree view you can find that these file not found